# PHP cURL get sent twice sometimes

Tags: php

I have an XML webservice URL that I do cURL requests to it.

My cURL request works fine but sometimes it is sent twice resulting in the user being charged twice.

So basically I have a form with an amount and the user clicks on submit to validate the payment. The form code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <title>Payment Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/spin.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#submit_btn_echeck').click(function () {
                    $('#cover-spin').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#cover-spin').hide();
                    }, 6000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="main_body" class="no_guidelines">
        <div id="form_container" class="StandShadow SLarge">
            <form action="pay_echeck/retained" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token_name" value="8825288f44db225ff01b86d3ec8c166c" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_to_pay" value="119.62" />
                <div class="form_description">
                    <h2>Payment Information</h2>
                    <p>Please review the details below before submitting your payment.</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="payment_summary">
                    <li class="payment_summary_amount">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="float:right;border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">Charge Amount:&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="border-left:1px dashed #ccc;border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;"><span style="float:right;">&#36;119.62</span></td>
                            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                <td style="float:right;"><b>TOTAL:&nbsp;</b></td>
                                <td style="border-left:1px dashed #ccc;"><span style="float:right;"><b id="totalCC">&nbsp;&#36;119.62</b></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                                                        
                    </li>   

                </ul>
                <input id="submit_btn_echeck" class="button_text btn_primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <div id="cover-spin"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the user submits the form I take the value of the hidden input named amount_to_pay and send it to the web-service via PHP cURL using the code below.

```
ob_start();  
$out = fopen('curl_log_'.date('mdY_his').'.txt', 'w');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mywebserviceurl.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//data sent as PHP XML object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__."/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__."/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'SoapAction; *']);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
$debug = ob_get_clean();
fwrite($out,$debug);
fwrite($out,$content);
fclose($out);
if (isset($content)) {
    return $content;
}
```

Everything works fine, some users pay with no issues but some others get charged twice and when I try to debug the curl request sent and the response received for one of those users for example I see that cURL request was sent twice. Below is a debug of the Curl request that was sent twice:

First request sent

```
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to webservice.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: .../application/libraries/cacert.pem
  CApath: .../application/libraries/cacert.pem
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.webservice.com
*  start date: Sep 13 15:44:59 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 13 15:44:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "webservice.com" matched cert's "webservice.com"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /ws/webservice_svc.cfc?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SoapAction: *
Content-Length: 939

* upload completely sent off: 939 out of 939 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 22:59:33 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 mod_jk/1.2.41
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
< Set-Cookie: CFID=2685691; Expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2019 **08:59:33 GMT**; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=d3c5d1e31b91dd7d-60FEB753-CF6E-1A16-AB0F8681EB1809A6; Expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2019 08:59:33 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://foundationtitlemelbourne.com/
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host webservice.com left intact
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:PayRPOResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws">
   <PayRPOReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;result&gt;Successful, 3990631&lt;/result&gt;</PayRPOReturn>
  </ns1:PayRPOResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Second same request sent, the only difference I see is that it was sent 8 seconds after the first one above

```
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to webservice.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: .../application/libraries/cacert.pem
  CApath: .../application/libraries/cacert.pem
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.webservice.com
*  start date: Sep 13 15:44:59 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 13 15:44:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "webservice.com" matched cert's "webservice.com"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /ws/webservice_svc.cfc?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SoapAction: *
Content-Length: 939

* upload completely sent off: 939 out of 939 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 22:59:33 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 mod_jk/1.2.41
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
< Set-Cookie: CFID=2685691; Expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2019 **08:59:41 GMT**; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=d3c5d1e31b91dd7d-60FEB753-CF6E-1A16-AB0F8681EB1809A6; Expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2019 08:59:33 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://foundationtitlemelbourne.com/
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host webservice.com left intact
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:PayRPOResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws">
   <PayRPOReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;result&gt;Successful, 3990631&lt;/result&gt;</PayRPOReturn>
  </ns1:PayRPOResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any lead or help please on what could be happening would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked to see (via your server logs) if the _form_ was also submitted twice?

Comment: How do I do that please? Which folder or log file should I check?

Comment: Most likely scenario is some users are clicking twice. (You'd be surprised how many users don't know when to click vs double-click.) You should add a check in the javascript or backed (both couldn't hurt) to catch that and block duplicate attempts

Comment: I'm already doing a spinner to prevent the user from clicking twice and also the input I have is "submit" type so when you click once, it submits the form and even if you try to click again, it does not send twice I think.

Comment: @OussamaKamal  You would check your webserver's access logs.  The location and filename can vary depending on which webserver you're using (apache, nginx, etc) and your specific configurations.  A common location for apache would be /var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: I checked in /var/log/apache2/access_log but I did not find any log on the time the request was made or the form was submitted. I do not think apache save a log when you submit a form does it?

Comment: @OussamaKamal  By default configuration, every request to the server is logged.  As I noted, your specific configurations may be different, writing the log to a different file.  Also, keep in mind that your server's timezone may not be the same as your own.  Another thing you can do to confirm this theory would be to add some custom logging in your form submit handler to write to a file of your choosing on each form submit.  Log the timestamp, IP, and probably some user-specific details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here:

```
                $('#cover-spin').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cover-spin').hide();
                }, 6000);
```

You are showing the submit button again after 6 seconds, so the user is likely to click it again, because it would seem as if the payment did not work the first time.

I would keep the `#cover_spin` visible, and let it disappear when the page navigates to the success or failure page.

I'd also disable the submit button after it is clicked for extra measure.

`$('#submit_btn_echeck').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I don't think so, when you click on submit button in a form, it is submitted to the POST url and even if you keep clicking, the form won't be sent twice unless you refresh the page or click on back button. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the payment gateway can respond twice for one payment request.

It is normal to happen, because the server which sends the response can be down for a period of time.
In this case the payment system tries to send the respond once, or multiple times.

It is your duty as a developer to treat this exception.

You can do it based on the id of the transaction send/retunred from the payment system.

Comment: Do you mean my apache server will try to send twice or more the same request as long as the server is not responding? I'm asking because not only the user is charged twice but he is sent an email from my script twice too which is of course normal as I send it when I receive a response, but doesn't it show that the problem can be coming from my server?

Comment: Can you try this things?

1.
Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to false and just do curl_exec($ch) instead of $content = trim(curl_exec($ch))
Then the curl output will be directly returned to the browser

2.
Set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to maximum php running script
Check for php running script and try to increase it a little if it's value is low

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);


3.
Check for multiple curl_init or curl_exec in your code


To answer your question, the server can respond twice if the connection is interrupted. Ex apache restart, php restart.